# (Rails) How to encrypt string by format method wp_hash_password of wp_user

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, wordpress, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a project use Wp 4.9.8, database migration from wp_user plugin.
I want to change project to Rails, and use old database (database create from WPress).

In table `wp_users`, column `password` has been encrypt.
I want to use rails insert new record with match format encrypt WP (method wp_hash_password )

exemple:

```
input: admin@123
output: $P$B67DM4HzC8jZG7t9RpL0XnlJxl4Zbf.
```

Tks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

The `wp_hash_password` format is as: `$hash_type$salt$password` so in general you can create this format in rails by concatenating few hashed segments in order as above.

To get more information about how WP generating `PasswordHash` here is public code implementation:

http://www.kvcodes.com/2016/09/wordpress-password-hash-generator/

It is too big to paste it here, so please check it on a link.